# RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

whenever I use RazorEngine in my application I get the following error:

{"FailedAt":"2014-11-12T02:51:59.9765953Z","ExceptionType":"RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to compile template. Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', you may need to supply runtime policy\n\nOther compilation errors may have occurred. Check the Errors property for more information.","ExceptionDetails":"RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException: Unable to compile template. Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', you may need to supply runtime policy\n\nOther compilation errors may have occurred. Check the Errors property for more information.\r\n   at RazorEngine.Compilation.DirectCompilerServiceBase.CompileType(TypeContext context) in c:\Users\abbottm\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Compilation\DirectCompilerServiceBase.cs:line 106\r\n   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplateType(String razorTemplate, Type modelType) in c:\Users\abbottm\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 256\r\n   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.GetTemplate[T](String razorTemplate, Object model, String cacheName) in c:\Users\abbottm\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 374\r\n   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.GetTemplate(String razorTemplate, Object model, String cacheName) in c:\Users\abbottm\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 352\r\n   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse(String razorTemplate, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag, String cacheName) in c:\Users\abbottm\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 437\r\n   at RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(String razorTemplate, Object model, String cacheName) in c:\Users\abbottm\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Razor.cs:line 302\r\n   at Postal.FileSystemRazorView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)\r\n   at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.RenderView(IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ControllerContext controllerContext, ImageEmbedder imageEmbedder)\r\n   at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.Render(Email email, String viewName)\r\n   at Postal.EmailService.CreateMailMessage(Email email)\r\n   at NumediaTechCore.UI.Controllers.Admin.EmailsController.SendEmail(Int32 EmailTemplateID) in c:\NumediaTech\NumediaTechPortal\NumediaTechCore\UI\Controllers\Admin\EmailsController.cs:line 105"}

Comment: You need to provide at least the complete exception (ie look into the errors property of the TemplateCompilationException as indicated in the message). There seem to be problems with compiling the template so providing the failing template could also help. Additionally you should mention the RazorEngine version you are using.